# Identify row index based on range of values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some data in it.

- One column **"DateTime"** has date and time (already formated to be understood as date and time using the command pd.to_datetime(...).
- Another column **"Current"** has values recorded during several days.

At the beginning, the data in the column "Current" changes from small values close to (-5, 0, +5) to values in a known range (let's say between -360 and -380). This goes on until I am not drawing current anymore. Then, the values are again close to 0.

I am basically trying to scan the dataframe and identify the first and last row where the values are between -360 and -380. Then, I want to use the row index and calculate the time interval between each of them.

My specific issue is to find the correct command and syntax to properly identify those two rows. Any clue ?

Here is a basic dataframe to illustrate. Basically, I'm looking for the index of rows 3 and 5. Once I have those rows, I can store this in a variable and then, calculate the equation (5 - 3).  (I'm sorry, I don't really know how to format the result, but the code is below...)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 6],[4,370],[5,370],[6,370],[7,-5],[8,2]], columns=['A', 'B'])

Ind A B
0 1 2 
1 2 3 
2 3 6 
3 4 370 
4 5 370 
5 6 370 
6 7 -5 
7 8 2
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello. 
I'm not sure how to include this.
I have the data into a Jupyter Notebook. Can I just drop some of the cells here ?

Comment: I edited the post. I'm currently trying out the solution of Dhanush1215 (below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
col = 'current'
minVal = -380
maxVal = -360
begin = df.loc[np.logical_and(df[col]<maxVal, df[col]>minVal)].index[0]
end = df.loc[np.logical_and(df[col]<maxVal, df[col]>minVal)].index[-1]
```

What it basically does is select all the values in your given range and get the min index and max index. Note that noisy data points may cause problems.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it will work. I was going around the problem the wrong way. I did not search for numpy, which is the package I should have looked into to do this logical test. 
Note that in your code, you have a ")" that should not be there (last line, just before index[-1]).

Question: Do I have to "mark" this as "resolved" ?